# Import diagram/structure inside a python folder (clean-up code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, code-organization, code-cleanup

I just finished a middle-sized python (3.6) project and I need to clean it a bit.
I am not a software engineer, so during the development, I was not too accurate structuring the project, so now I have several modules that are no (longer) imported by any other module or modules that are imported by other .py files that are not actually needed.

So for example, I have

```
Project/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── foo.py
|
├── tools/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tool1.py
│   └── tool2.py
│   └── tool3.py
|
├── math/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── math1.py
│   └── math2.py
├── graph/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── graph1.py
│   ├── graph2.py
│
```

and inside

main.py

```py
from math import math1
from tools import tool2
```

graph1.py

```py
from math import math1
from tools import tool1, tool2
```

foo.py

```py
from tools import tool3
```

If I could see in one look that not a module imports `graph2` or `math2`, I could delete them, or at least add them as candidates for deletion (and restructure the project in a better way).
Or I may think to delete `tool3` because I know I don't need `foo` anymore.

Is there an easy way to visualize all the "connections" (which module imports which) in a diagram or some other kind of structured data/visualization manner?

Comment: Hm, I am not aware of any package that could do this, but what you want to visualise is called a „dependency graph”. That is, a structure which explains which module depends on which other one.

What I'd do (while using git for source code versioning) is to delete files and see, whether the python program still runs.

My code is written in such a way, that every `__init__.py` is re-exporting the relevant classes / constants etc. of that directory level. This way, I can replace the directory with a `.py` or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python to do the work for you:

Place a Python file with the following code into the same directory as your Project directory.

```
from pathlib import Path

# list all the modules you want to check:
modules = ["tool1", "tool2", "tool3", "math1", "math2", "graph1", "graph2"]

# find all the .py files within your Project directory (also searches subdirectories):
p = Path('./Project')
file_list = list(p.glob('**/*.py'))

# check, which modules are used in each .py file:
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        print('*'*10, file, ':')
        file_as_string = f.read()
        for module in modules:
            if module in file_as_string:
                print(module)
```

Running this will give you an output looking something like this:

```
********** Project\main.py :
tool1
tool2
graph1
********** Project\foo.py :
tool2
********** Project\math\math1.py :
tool2
math2
```

Comment: If you want to read up on the Python functions I used for this code, you can check out https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html and https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp  ;)

Comment: Thank you, I tried something "homemade" like this too. Your way might add to the list also if, for example, 'tool1' is a variable in the .py file, so I use to read the file line by line and look for lines with ```module in fileline and 'import' in fileline```. I also added several other conditions to filter out commented lines and so on. Still a "backup solution" (but I did learn about `pathlib` )

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a Unix-like platform (such as macOS), you can find all files containing specific text with [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). So you could search for all files containing ''import math1'' in your Project directory, for example, with `grep -rnw '/path/to/Project/' -e 'import math1'` , and if there are no results, then you can safely remove the module. All this process can be easily automated with a python or a shell script!

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I work with windows, I will edit the post to specify it. I may have the opportunity to do this check with a virtual machine but I was kinda looking for a more straight forward solution. But yes, this is a good hint if I cannot find any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this project](https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps) can help you with visualizing your dependency graph. After a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=IaCHXv2PEuelytMPg8GWmAs&q=python%20visualize%20dependency%20graph&oq=python%20visualize%20dependency%20graph&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR0oJCBcSBTEyLTIxSggIGBIEMTItNFAAWABgvyJoAHAEeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi9pJDZj83oAhXnknIEHYOgBbMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), it looks like you're not the first person to try to do this.

Comment: I actually tried this before (I should have mentioned in the post). Unfortunately this is pretty buggy. It returns some "maximum recursion depth error" when running it on a folder (at least mine). I then made a script to run it on all the .py files of the given folder and looks like it "forgets" some import instruction (I could not find much consistency but many times looks like it cannot parse instructions like ```from foo import bar```)